# iOS 4 Safari and Android 2.3 Browser Modernizr / matchMedia / Enquire.js Cache Issues

Tags: javascript, ios4, modernizr, android-2.3-gingerbread, enquire.js

I'm doing some basic toggleClass functions using enquire.js for some of my responsive projects.

For older browsers such as Android 2.3 and below and iOS 4 Safari, the following example does not work.

I am doing some modernizr testing as you can see below. Older Android browsers and iOS 4 Safar do not support matchMedia, hence the matchMedia polyfill.

I have created a test case and tested it using BrowserStack, and it fails on iOS 4 and below. http://goo.gl/3a3ss, or a fiddle that may or may not work.. http://jsfiddle.net/jSg6X/

Originally this is used on a Drupal site. On initial load, everything works. If you refresh the page or try to go to another page, the script fails at the matchMedia test. If you clear the browser cache and reload, it works again but just for that page.

(function ($, window, document) {

```
Modernizr.load([
    {
        test: Modernizr.mq('only all'),
        nope: 'js/respond.min.js'
    },
    {
        test: window.matchMedia,
        nope: 'js/matchMedia.js'
    },
    {
        load: 'js/enquire.min.js',
        complete: function(){
            var query = "all and (max-width:600px)";
            var $myButton1  = $(".mybutton1");
                            var $myButton2  = $(".mybutton2");
            enquire.register(query, [
            {
                match: function(){
                    $myButton1.on("click", function(){
                            $(".menu").toggleClass("showme");
                    });
                },
                unmatch: function(){
                    $myButton1.off("click");
                },
                                    match: function(){
                                            $myButton2.on("click", function(){
                                                $(".menu2").toggleClass("showme");
                                            });
                                    },
                                    unmatch: function(){
                                            $myButton2.off("click");
                                    }
            }
            ],true).listen();
        }
    }
]);
```

})(jQuery, this, this.document);

Any help would be appreciated. I am not sure if I am not using enquire.js correctly, or I am missing something.

I have created a further reduced test case without, and am getting thes ame result. I used the below js (doesn't make sense, I know, but it loads the alert on first load and that's it)

(function ($, window, document) {

Modernizr.load([
    //first test need for matchMedia polyfill
    {
      test: window.matchMedia,
      nope: 'js/media.match.min.js',
      load: 'js/enquire.min.js',
      callback: function(){
        alert("test");
      }
    }
]);

})(jQuery, this, this.document);

Comment: Hey @briggimus, as per my comment on twitter, could you look at creating a JSFiddle/codepen with a reduced test case.

Answer (score 0):

This has been somewhat addressed by this Github issue for Android 2.3 and iOS 4.

https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/issues/95